# Netsuite Advanced PDF - Retrieve Custom Preferences

Tags: netsuite

Is there a method in NetSuite's Advanced PDFs to access Custom Preferences?

I am creating a bundle of Advanced PDFs to deploy to customer's, and I'd like to be able to Store "Logo Dimensions" in the custom preferences so the customer can change the form logo, and set the width/height of the logo without needing to edit the Advanced PDF itself.

Comment: How is the template being invoked? What Suitescript version?

Comment: Standard method of printing.  Not scripted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a beforeLoad user event script. Give it the parameters you want to manage.

Check that the event type is ‘print’. Set a hidden custom field on the record with the parameter value. Use that value on your PDF template